# React or NPM issue?

Tags: reactjs, npm

Good Evening All! Hope today was great coding day for everyone.  Quick question..

After running the “npx create-react-app” command I get the following error message in my terminal

> Cannot find module ‘./internal/Observable’ Require stack:
>
> /Users/FInnocent/node_modules/rxjs/index.js
> /Users/FInnocent/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js
> /Users/FInnocent/node_modules/inquirer/lib/inquirer.js
> /Users/FInnocent/node_modules/create-react-app/createReactApp.js
> /Users/FInnocent/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js

I’m running version v12.16.2 of node and 6.14.4 of npm.

I’ve tried searching for this error in StackOverlow but no luck. I also tried to install this module by running

```
npm install ./internal/Observable” and get the following error:

npm ERR! Could not install from “internal/Observable” as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

Any ideas on what’s wrong and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution actually, I ran the following

```
npm install rxjs
```

And i’m all set now